# phpmyadmin - Sum all columns into one column

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I have a database with a lot of columns with different values.

[image]

Is it possible to add the sum of all the columns into one column single column? So 200+ columns will become one column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I see it correctly this is a table and no database and than this are rows and not coloumns. 
So if the screenshot you posted is everything you have, it is simply:

```
SELECT SUM(<ColoumnTitle>) As <newColoumnTitle>
FROM <TableName>;
```

If this is not the only table, I need more information.